# Can't access Websites in Azure portal - Red exclamation mark

Tags: azure

I'm trying to open my Websites in Azure portal and there is a red exclamation

I write a ticket but i have not answer yet.

Comment: Which portal (Azure currently has two, as they are slowly transitioning from one to the other)? portal.azure.com or manage.windowsazure.com?

Comment: the old one manage.windowsazure.com i found this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c8fedebf-41a7-44f3-81a7-c1f6ad4c35d4/portal-issue-on-websites-and-mobile-services?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview @JayHarris

Answer (score 0):

ISSUE of Azure Team (Portal Issue on Websites and Mobile Services)
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c8fedebf-41a7-44f3-81a7-c1f6ad4c35d4/portal-issue-on-websites-and-mobile-services?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview